# BLDC winding architecture

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, winding

I was dissecting an out-runner BLDC - 24s28p configuration. I came across a winding pattern I've not seen before. Unwinding one tooth I counted 7 in hand for 8 turns clockwise, and it continued onto the adjacent tooth with 9 turns anti-clockwise. Can someone explain the reasoning for not only the winding pattern of clockwise, then anti-clockwise on adjacent teeth, but also the imbalance in the number of adjacent tooth windings (8, then 9 on the adjacent)?

Comment: Instead of saying CW or CCW, it'd be better to say left-hand or right hand, and towards or away from the center. Better yet, draw a picture.

Comment: related https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/593947/brushless-drone-motor-with-14-poles-and-12-coil-12-slot-stator

Comment: @BruceAbbott thanks - exactly what I was looking for.